# is there a design pattern that allows modelling different actions for different roles?

Tags: design-patterns

We have a requirement where depending on the role the user has, they get to different options in a drop down menu. (The selected option will drive actions on the record)

This was originally implemented, not by me, I hasten to add, by using if statements, and storing the allowed options in a an array.

As predicted, the "rules" have become more complex and new roles have been added so that it now has become an unholy mess of spaghetti code, which might actually required adding dummy variables to keep track of what is going on.

My question is, is there a design pattern that can help to solve this problem?

An example

Role **Approver** will only see **Approve**, **Reject** and **Submitted for Approval** if reading a record that they don't own. If they own the record, then they can only see **Reject**

Role **CSA** can see **Reviewed**, **Approve** or **Needs Rework** for if reading a record that has not been rejected, if it has been rejected then, well it becomes to complex to explain succinctly.

We have 3 more roles ... :(

Comment: I would give State pattern a try.

Comment: Specification pattern may work too.

Comment: Related question, with an answer of the [Interceptor pattern](http://www.cs.rit.edu/usr/local/pub/jeh/courses/AOP/Handouts/Interceptor.pdf): http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/208855/standard-practices-for-access-control-design-pattern

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible solution can the [Decorator design pattern](http://www.dofactory.com/net/decorator-design-pattern), hence it adds responsibilities to objects dynamically. Also provides a flexible alternative to subclassing for extending functionality. In your case the implementation can be something like this:

```
//Component
public abstract class Option{   
    // defines the interface for objects that can have responsibilities added to them dynamically.
}

//ConcreteComponent 
public class ApproveOption extends Option{
    //defines an object to which additional responsibilities can be attached.
}

//ConcreteComponent 
public class RejectOption extends Option{
    //defines an object to which additional responsibilities can be attached.
}

public abstract class Decorator{   
    //maintains a reference to a Component object and defines an interface that conforms to 
    //Component's interface.
}

public class OptionsDecorator extends Decorator{   
    //adds (Visible) responsibilities to the component depending from the Role.
}
```

Or via [State design pattern](http://www.dofactory.com/net/state-design-pattern) to allow an object to alter its behavior when its internal state changes. The object will appear to change its class. And become:

```
//Context
public class Role{  
    //defines the interface of interest to clients
    //maintains an instance of a ConcreteState subclass that defines the current state.
}

public abstract class State{
    //defines an interface for encapsulating the behavior associated with a particular state 
    //of the Context.
}

//Concrete State
public class ApproverState extends State{
    //each subclass implements a behavior associated with a state of Context
}

public class CSAState extends State{
    //each subclass implements a behavior associated with a state of Context
}
```

Comment: I was thinking about the state design pattern but hadn't considered the decorator pattern, I'll try to do a POC of both and see which one works best. Thanks

Comment: Decorator makes sense if the *same operation* gets done differently. Each decorator can redefine the operation (augment it). The OP clearly states that they are different operations according to the role. It seems not to fit well, at least not the way you've explained it. State pattern might make sense, but again you didn't flesh out the operations. I don't think this answer's detailed enough.